# Publishing feature enable - break permissions or something

Tags: publishing, access-denied

I created a brand new team site and I activated the Publishing feature at the site collection level and next thing I know of farm admin can't access the site anymore and is getting an access denied message. So I quickly deactivated the feature with powershell. What would cause this and how to go by fixing this issue? I haven't seen this error within 5/6 years of working with this.

Comment: Is the team site template modified in any way? Or any features activated automatically?

Comment: It's a brand new farm with the sts#0 team site ootb template. No modifications at all.